# CSS browser compatibility

Tags: css

Is there a tool what will load my css and then analyzes it and then generates/shows me what to add/change to make it more compatible with other browsers?

Comment: Sounds like a great tool! I know of browsershots.org, but all of the CSS analysers I know of only tell you if your CSS is valid, which should be good for ALL browsers...

Comment: tahdhaze09, do i smell sarcasm in your comment? (:

Comment: A CSS validator is just the first step. Valid CSS is not sure to work in IE7.

Comment: hs2d - Noooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sitebuilder's job is not just to write some CSS that he thinks is cool. It is also a part of the job, to test it against different browsers, the number depending on which ones are supported in the project.

I don't think there can be a tool that can do our job instead of us. All that a sitebuilder can and should do, is collecting knowledge, experience and keeping up with the browsers and techniques. There are no exact rules how to handle cross-browser issues. There are loads of best practices, tips and tricks, and it's always the sitebuilder who has to decide which one to use in that certain situation.

What we have, is great tools to check out our pages in certain browsers, one being what @Thorben suggested.

And I have to add that this is just my opinion, feel free to disagree and argue :).

Comment: Yes, but it would be nice to compare my css against some set of rules and then get back the result with the suggestions. It really would save up some time. For example when i use "opacity: 1" in my css it suggest to add "-moz-opacity: 1" and etc.

Comment: And just to mention, the point is not doing the work for u, but just gathering all the tips and tricks and use them in a tool.

Comment: Here's a something like it.http://rails-bestpractices.com/ There is a gem what smelles your code. Community who creates best practices and votes for them and then solves them. Afther when u run the tool it and finds a smell shows u a link to a solved best practice to show u how u should do it. (: Just think best practices as cross browser errors/tips&tricks.

Comment: Just imagine how hard would it be to create such a tool and keep it always up to date. For example: Firefox X.Y decides to use opacity instead of -moz-opacity, because the standard is accepted. Should the tool still note this, or not? Maybe you want to still cater for Firefox X-1. Or who could decide that?

Comment: It's very different to provide such a tool for a programming language, we have these for several langs and they are great.

Comment: Yes, ok. I got your point. It would be really hard to keep up with the browsers changing so fast. Still i think it would be create tool (:

Answer (score 2):

There are online tools launching your website in many different browsers taking a screenshot and then display them to you. That way you can check by yourself!

Just google for it or try http://browsershots.org/